# Атрибуты через дефис и теги камел-кейсом

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Сайт сделан на реакте и нужно вставить на него большую (в плане строк кода) svg. Сайт начинает посылать варнинги:

> index.js:1 Warning: Invalid DOM property `clip-rule`. Did you mean `clipRule`?

Вопрос: как можно решить эту проблему, не прибегая к переписыванию атрибутов? Возможно, эти варнинги можно отключить или есть онлайн сервисы по переписыванию тегов svg в jsx?

SVG на подобии:

```html
<svg width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 60 60" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M25.2825 40.0594C24.7087 40.9416 24.375 41.9944 24.375 43.125C22.5 44.0625 19.6875 44.0625 18.75 43.125C17.5603 41.9353 17.8125 41.25 15 39.375C14.3728 38.9569 13.8319 38.8397 13.3866 38.7816C13.1194 38.82 12.8991 39.0122 12.8231 39.2719C12.7481 39.5306 12.8316 39.811 13.0359 39.9872C13.7681 40.5553 14.7459 41.4253 15 42.1875C15.9375 45 17.8125 46.875 20.625 46.875C22.3219 46.875 23.5275 46.6294 24.375 46.3153V50.5031C24.375 51.7791 23.7262 52.9687 22.6528 53.6587C21.5784 54.3487 20.2275 54.4453 19.0659 53.9147C10.0388 49.7288 3.75 40.5928 3.75 30C3.75 15.5119 15.5119 3.75 30 3.75C44.4881 3.75 56.25 15.5119 56.25 30C56.25 40.5928 49.9613 49.7287 40.9163 53.8762C39.7678 54.4003 38.4319 54.3047 37.3706 53.6231C36.3084 52.9406 35.6663 51.765 35.6663 50.5031C35.625 47.0484 35.625 43.125 35.625 43.125C35.625 42.0291 35.3053 40.965 34.7166 40.0594C41.7525 39.1988 45 36.0075 45 28.5938C45 26.0409 44.1337 23.9203 42.7397 22.2169C43.4634 20.2641 43.6453 17.9344 43.3266 15.9431C43.2778 15.6909 43.1288 15.4697 42.9122 15.3309C42.6966 15.1931 42.4331 15.15 42.1838 15.2109C39.7388 15.8156 37.8169 16.7466 36.3956 17.9906C34.29 17.2425 32.0531 16.875 30 16.875C27.9469 16.875 25.71 17.2425 23.6044 17.9906C22.1831 16.7466 20.2612 15.8156 17.8162 15.2109C17.5669 15.15 17.3034 15.1931 17.0878 15.3309C16.8712 15.4697 16.7222 15.6909 16.6734 15.9431C16.3547 17.9344 16.5366 20.2641 17.2603 22.2169C15.8663 23.9203 15 26.0409 15 28.5938C15 36.0066 18.2475 39.1978 25.2825 40.0594Z" fill="#738B95"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M21.5016 54.15C20.6972 54.3431 19.8394 54.2681 19.0659 53.9147C10.0388 49.7288 3.75 40.5928 3.75 30C3.75 15.5119 15.5119 3.75 30 3.75C30.2944 3.75 30.5869 3.7547 30.8766 3.76408C16.7934 4.22908 5.50406 15.8062 5.50406 30C5.50406 40.5928 11.7919 49.7288 20.82 53.9147C21.0413 54.0159 21.27 54.0938 21.5016 54.15ZM43.0603 15.4491C43.3453 15.3647 43.6378 15.2859 43.9378 15.2109C44.1863 15.15 44.4506 15.1931 44.6663 15.3309C44.8828 15.4697 45.0319 15.6909 45.0797 15.9431C45.3984 17.9344 45.2175 20.2641 44.4937 22.2169C45.8878 23.9203 46.7541 26.0409 46.7541 28.5938C46.7541 36.0075 43.5056 39.1988 36.4706 40.0594C37.0584 40.965 37.3791 42.0291 37.3791 43.125C37.3791 43.125 37.3791 47.0484 37.4203 50.5031C37.4203 51.765 38.0625 52.9406 39.1237 53.6231C39.4753 53.8481 39.8569 54.0103 40.2525 54.1059C39.2756 54.3441 38.2331 54.1772 37.3706 53.6231C36.3084 52.9406 35.6663 51.765 35.6663 50.5031C35.625 47.0484 35.625 43.125 35.625 43.125C35.625 42.0291 35.3053 40.965 34.7166 40.0594C41.7525 39.1988 45 36.0075 45 28.5938C45 26.0409 44.1337 23.9203 42.7397 22.2169C43.4634 20.2641 43.6453 17.9344 43.3266 15.9431C43.29 15.7538 43.1963 15.5813 43.0603 15.4491ZM24.375 46.7428C23.8003 46.8253 23.1384 46.875 22.3791 46.875C22.1513 46.875 21.9291 46.8628 21.7144 46.8384C22.8544 46.7587 23.7216 46.5572 24.375 46.3153V46.7428ZM14.6241 39.1528C14.7244 38.955 14.9156 38.8144 15.1406 38.7816C15.5859 38.8397 16.1259 38.9569 16.7541 39.375C19.5666 41.25 19.3134 41.9353 20.5041 43.125C20.8416 43.4625 21.4228 43.6791 22.1156 43.7728C20.7169 43.9406 19.35 43.725 18.75 43.125C17.5603 41.9353 17.8125 41.25 15 39.375C14.8706 39.2887 14.7459 39.2156 14.6241 39.1528ZM30.8766 16.8975C31.1719 16.8825 31.4653 16.875 31.7541 16.875C33.4003 16.875 35.1647 17.1113 36.8841 17.5913C36.7153 17.7206 36.5522 17.8538 36.3956 17.9906C34.5862 17.3475 32.6803 16.9856 30.8766 16.8975ZM18.6928 15.4491C18.7378 15.405 18.7875 15.3656 18.8409 15.3309C19.0575 15.1931 19.3209 15.15 19.5703 15.2109C21.7453 15.7491 23.5069 16.5459 24.8691 17.5913C24.4444 17.7094 24.0216 17.8425 23.6044 17.9906C22.3575 16.8994 20.7253 16.0491 18.6928 15.4491Z" fill="#617881"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Какие именно теги? В каком месте в коде вы объявляете svg? Где используете `clip-rule`?

Comment: @DiD, перепутал атрибуты и теги

Comment: Ну для svg это нормальные атрибуты, странно, что ругается.

Comment: @DiD, я приложение создавал через create react app, скорее всего из-за этого